# Apache Flink - Unable to get the filename after writing the csv file to S3

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am using Apache Flink with programming language as Java to write a csv file to s3 using the FileSink Library.

Csv Data is successfully written to s3 file. But my requirement is to return the name of the file written in s3.

I have configured the Prefix and suffix as "test" and ".csv" respectively. But Flink adds its own UUID to the filename such as "test-2ea1c0a5-86c4-4af3-b61a-3c2ea4c1bce8-0.csv".

Code Snippet:

```
FileSink<RowData> sink = FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path(s3FilePath), new SerializationSchemaAdapter(serSchemaBuilder))
                    .withOutputFileConfig(new OutputFileConfig("test", ".csv"))
                    .build();
rowData.sinkTo(sink);
```

Can anyone please let me know how to obtain this filename from the sink response?
OR
Is this filename configurable ?